# fastest way to read this type of input from command line in python

Tags: python, user-input

I am trying to solve this [TSORT](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT) and it needs a fast version of input and output,

I tried using `int(raw_input())` for each line and counting sort but it was not efficient enough so is there any other way,

I tried `fileinput.input()` but I cant have it end at the right time

the input is of type :

`5 #number of lines unto 10^6, and each value is from 0 to 10^6
3 
8 
9 
1 
7`

Comment: Did you profile it? was the input the main problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "from command line"?  Do you mean that you want a one-line Python program that can be written entirely at a shell prompt (e.g. `python -c 'print "Hello world";'`)?

Comment: @dg99: I mean when the input numbers are entered from command line one by one rather than a file input

Answer (score 0):

using `sys.stdin` seems to be quite a bit faster then `raw_input`.  maybe like this

```
n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
print '\n'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, sys.stdin))))
```